# What listbox event should I use to set scroll position

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listbox, updatepanel, position

on my page, I have a listbox in an update panel.  I am successfully trapping the scroll position, however when the update panel refreshes, I'm having trouble finding a suitable javascript event in which to call my function to set the scroll position.  Any ideas?

i had really hoped that "onAfterUpdate" was going to work, but no...

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "update panel" and "listbox"?  Neither of these are core JS/HTML components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the request and UpdatePanel is finished you can tap into the PageRequestManager and fire your own delegate:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
   //your code here
}
</script>
```